# Seasoned Schemer's get-first, get-next, and waddle functions

Tags: scheme, continuations, callcc, seasoned-schemer

```
(define get-first
  (lambda (l)
    (call-with-current-continuation
      (lambda (here)
        (set! leave here)
        (waddle l)
        (leave (quote ()))))))

(define get-first
  (lambda (l)
    (call-with-current-continuation
      (lambda (here)
        (set! leave here)
        (leave (waddle l))))))
```

For anybody not familiar with the book "The Seasoned Schemer", `get-first`, `get-next`, and `waddle` (last two not defined here) are procedures to apparently model *coroutines* to iterate through a *tree* passed to `waddle` that yields leaves only.  Just prior to `waddle`'s yield on its second-to-last re-entry, it sets the re-entry point to where it will only ever return the pure value `'()` i.e. instead of yielding `'()` , the *actual value* of `waddle` *is* `'()` , as if it were a pure function all along.

With this in mind, we can see what `get-first` sets up... When `waddle` returns "for real", it will be inside the `call/cc` in `get-first` and then `(leave (quote ()))` is the value of `get-first` (and, in turn, this `leave` is intended to return to `get-next` on the last iteration, therefore it is `get-next` that does the "actual" return of `'()`).

So why is the second version not equivalent, where `waddle`'s value of `'()` would be the argument to `leave`?

Comment: Nevermind... the confusion is because "leave" is not the function I *want* it to be, but the function it evaluates to when its evaluated, which appears to be left-to-right and thus before "waddle".  That means it evaluates to what it was just set to in the statement prior.

Moral: beware when using functions that are subject to redefining WITHIN the call to the function!  If this was on a right-to-left interpreter, waddle would be evaluated before the symbol leave was looked up as the function that leaves to wherever, during which time it would be set to a DIFFERENT function.  What a mess...

Comment: Glad to hear it's resolved, but please post the resolution as an answer (rather than a comment here), and accept it. That way people can see the question is resolved without coming in here.

Comment: @user1457584 both versions won't compile: `set!: unbound identifier in module in: leave`

Answer (score 4):

The confusion is because "`leave`" is not the function I want it to be, but the function it evaluates to *when* it's evaluated, which appears to be left-to-right and thus before "`waddle`". That means it evaluates to what it was just set to, in the statement prior.

Moral: beware when using functions that are subject to redefining WITHIN the call to the function! If this was on a right-to-left interpreter, `waddle` would be evaluated before the symbol `leave` was looked up as the function that "leaves" to wherever, during which time it would be set to a DIFFERENT function.

Comment: You should mark your question answered, even though you wrote the answer.  Otherwise it shows up on the unanswered list.