# get-first - the-seasoned-schemer

Tags: scheme, continuations, callcc, seasoned-schemer

Please take a look at `two-in-a-row*?` function in chapter 19.

My question is about the `(leave '())` in the `get-first` helper function. Note that `(waddle l)` will either return `'()` or an atom, which indicates the list has exhausted or an atom from the list is retrieved.

Without `(leave '())` it will still return those two kinds of values, just not use the continuation `leave`. But the book says without `(leave '())` is bad, I just can not see why.

```
(define two-in-a-row*
  (letrec ([leave id] ; the identity function 
           [fill id]
           [waddle (lambda (l)
                     (cond [(null? l) '()]
                           [(atom? (car l))
                            (begin 
                              (letcc rest
                                     (set! fill rest)
                                     (leave (car l)))
                              (waddle (cdr l)))]
                           [else
                            (begin
                              (waddle (car l))
                              (waddle (cdr l)))]))]
           [get-first (lambda (l)
                        (letcc here
                               (set! leave here)
                               (waddle l)
                               (leave '()) ; why is this part needed???
                               ))]
           [get-next (lambda (l)
                       (letcc here
                              (set! leave here)
                              (fill 'go)))]
           [T? (lambda (a)
                 (let ([n (get-next 'dummy)])
                   (if (atom? n)
                       (or (eq? a n)
                           (T? n))
                       #f)))])
    (lambda (l)
      (let ([fst (get-first l)])
        (if (atom? fst)
            (T? fst)
            #f)))))
```

Thanks very much.

Another interesting [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043704/seasoned-schemer-get-first-get-next-and-waddle?rq=1) about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks for Will Ness's examples. I went over some even simpler ones. So "what is it so bad about that?" -- without `(leave '())` in `get-first`.

**Short Answer:**
Note that from my code
i) `leave` will always be recreated each time when we call `get-first` or `get-next`. It will return to either `get-first` or `get-next`.
ii) `fill` will result to be a chain depending on previous `fill`, and it will always return to `get-first`.

**Example**
Input: `'(1)`

So we start by evaluating `get-first` on `'(1)`.
i) set `leave`
ii) start `(waddle '(1)`
iii) since `1` is an atom, so set `fill` to be current continuation. Note if we use `fill`, then it will go to do `(waddle (cdr l))`, then **it will return to `get-first`**.
iv) return to `get-first` by using `leave` with return value `1`.

Then we go to eval `(T? 1)`, which will in turn go to run `get-next`.
i) set `leave`
ii) run `fill`
iii) start `(waddle '())`
iv) return `()` from `waddle`, then return to `get-first`.

**Note**
1) If we don't have `(leave '()`, then `get-first` will return `'()`, then the `two-in-a-row*` return `#f`. So we can get the same answer, but the behavior is not what we want.
2) If we have it, then note that `leave` is now the `leave` created by `get-next`, thus it is going to transfer `'()` to `get-next`.
3) With more than 1 input in the list when we create `fill` it will be created based on previous `fill`, thus result to be a chain depending previous `fill`.

Answer (score 2):

The naming looks off. I used "yield" for "leave", and "next" for "fill". I also had to define `atom?` and re-write `letcc` as `call/cc`, to make it work in Racket. Here's the full code:

```
(define two-in-a-row*
  (letrec ([yield '()] 
           [next '()]
           [atom? (lambda (x) (and (not (null? x))
                                   (not (pair? x))))]
           [waddle (lambda (l)
                     (cond [(null? l) '()]
                           [(atom? (car l))
                            (begin 
                              (call/cc (lambda ( here2 )
                                          (set! next here2)
                                          (yield (car l))))
                              (waddle (cdr l)))]
                           [else
                            (begin (waddle (car l))
                                   (waddle (cdr l)))]))]
           [get-first (lambda (l)
                        (call/cc (lambda ( here1 )
                                    (set! yield here1)
                                    (waddle l)
                                    (yield '()) ; why is this part needed???
                                    )))]
           [get-next (lambda ()
                       (call/cc (lambda ( here3 )
                                   (set! yield here3)
                                   (next 'dummy))))]
           [T? (lambda (a)
                 (let ([n (get-next)])  (display (list "next:" n))
                   (and (atom? n)
                        (or (eq? a n)
                            (T? n)))))])
    (lambda (l)
      (let ([a (get-first l)])
        (and (begin                     (display (list "first:" a))
                    (atom? a))
             (T? a))))))
```

We can see the difference here:

```
(two-in-a-row* '(((7) (b)) c (d)))
  ; w/out yield () : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: c)(next: d)(first: ())#f
  ; w/    yield () : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: c)(next: d)(next: ())#f
  ; w/    yield #f : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: c)(next: d)(next: #f)(next: #f)#t

(two-in-a-row* '(((7) (b)) c ()))
  ; w/out yield () : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: c)(first: ())#f
  ; w/    yield () : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: c)(next: ())#f
  ; w/    yield #f : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: c)(next: #f)(next: #f)#t

(two-in-a-row* '(((7) (b)) b ()))
  ; w/out yield () : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: b)#t
  ; w/    yield () : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: b)#t
  ; w/    yield #f : (first: 7)(next: b)(next: b)#t
```

Comment: Hi @Will Ness, Great !!! I understand now how it is working exactly. I will give you credits for this. I will write up the whole thing in another answer.

Comment: @Lingxiao Glad it helped you somehow. This one is a real mind-bender. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky. The clue in the book is the `wow!` reply. The student is saying `wow!` because they've realised `()` is returned from a different function.

This isn't clear, neither in the book or by using drracket, and it took me a while to understand but the key to understanding this is:

1. `get-first` called `waddle` to make the `fill` continuation.
2. `waddle` (when not using continuations) returns to `get-first`.

But

1. `get-next` calls `fill`.
2. `fill` continues in `waddle`
3. `waddle` uses `leave` to return to `get-next` rather than `get-first`.

But in the case of `(waddle '())`, `waddle` does not use `leave` to return to `get-next`. It returns normally. And that means it returns to `get-first`.

This means that `get-next` won't actually get the `()` return value. It won't get this value because `waddle` is returning to `get-first` instead.

Now comes to interesting part.

1. We know that, for the value `()`, `waddle` returns to `get-first` when we want it to return to `get-next`.
2. We know that `get-next` sets `leave` to return to `get-next`.
3. Therefore,  `get-first` can use `leave` to return to `get-next`.

The real reason this is tricky is because look at the scenario when you don't use `(leave '())` in `get-first`.

1. `fill` calls waddle with `()`.
2. `waddle` returns to `get-first`.
3. `get-first` then returns `()`.

And this is equivalent to:

```
  (let ([fst '()])     ;; was (let ([fst (get-first l)])
    (if (atom? fst)
        (T? fst)
        #f)))))
```

Which returns the same value as the version that returns into `get-next`:

```
       [T? (lambda (a)
             (let ([n '()])      ;; was (let ([n (get-next 'dummy)])
               (if (atom? n)
                   (or (eq? a n)
                       (T? n))
                   #f)))])
```

Both are `#f`, but only accidentally! No one said the book wouldn't make you think ;)